# Customizing basemap in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, topology, basemap

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.

I would like to customize the World Terrain Basemap in order to select which roads and topography labels appear.

Is there a way to do this, and if not, then how would I create my own hillshade terrain basemap with a selection of topography features?

Comment: Do you mean topography rather than topology?

Answer (score 0):

The World Terrain Basemap is a map service you get from Esri. So I don't think you can customizing the basemap directly.

To create your own hillshade terrain basemap, you need to create a mxd file with the topography features and set the map symbolization by yourself first.
Then publish the mxd as a web map service / web map tiled service by ArcGIS Server.